# Android reports file sizes different than windows

Tags: file-system

Android and windows report different file sizes for the same files. why is that?

Looking at two video files, on device both the Gallery and file manager report a certain size, but browsing to those files on Windows 10 (USB connected)- shows they're significantly **smaller**

- Vid A

  - Android: 2.289GB
  - Windows: 2.13 GB (2,294,649,056 bytes)
  - Difference: +7.46% on Android
- Vid B

  - Android: 394MB
  - Windows: 375 MB (393,532,962 bytes)
  - Difference: +5.1% on Android

Windows shows more specificity, so I assume it's correct.
Is android just approximating? 5-7% seems like a pretty big difference to me.

Phone: LG G7, Android 9
Windows: 10 Build 19042

Comment: Possibly due to [*kilo*byte vs *kibi*byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units) Both showing almost the same bytes though.

Comment: Vid B is pretty much clear (375 MiB = 394 MB) but for Vid A you made a mistake (2.13 GiB > 2.289 GB) windows is bigger than android because space occupied on windows disk (in bytes) is not equal file size in bytes

Comment: In addition to MB vs MiB difference already mentioned, recommended read: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120312/262728). Or at least understand how `du -b` and `du -B1` differ. [`du` manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html).